# How to call the parameter of that stored Type and procedure in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, json, sql-server

I'm using postman to insert or update a giving array with nodejs into SQL Server database table. I'm trying to insert 'user or benutzer' if the id not exist and to update if id exist.

That's how I create my database table:

```
create Table benutzer (
    id int primary key not null,
    firstName nvarchar(200) not null,
    lastname nvarchar(200) not null,
    active bit not null
)
```

Here is my stored Procedure in SQL Server:

```
USE benutzerDb;
GO

CREATE TYPE BenutzerList AS TABLE (
    [b_id] INT,
    b_firstName NVARCHAR(200),
    b_lastName NVARCHAR(200),
    b_active bit
);
GO

CREATE PROC updateBenutzer (@benutzerList BenutzerList READONLY)

AS

BEGIN

    MERGE benutzer AS ben

        USING @benutzerList AS blist

    ON ben.id = blist.[b_id]

    WHEN MATCHED THEN

        UPDATE SET 

        ben.firstName = blist.b_firstName,
        ben.lastName = blist.b_lastName,
        ben.active = blist.b_active

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN

        INSERT (id,firstName,lastName,active)

        VALUES (blist.b_id, blist.b_firstName, blist.b_lastName, blist.b_active);

    select * from @benutzerList

END

GO
```

->and hier how called in SqlServer and it's work perfekt:

```
use benutzerDb

go

DECLARE @benutzerList BenutzerList

INSERT INTO @benutzerList VALUES(1,'Max','Müller',1),(15,'Ben','Kane',1)

EXEC updateBenutzer @benutzerList

SELECT * FROM benutzer
```

-> and hier ist my function:

```
//function to add or update benutzer:

async  function  addBenutzer() {

  try {

  const benutzerTable = new sql.Table();

  benutzerTable.columns.add('b_id', sql.Int);

  benutzerTable.columns.add('b_firstName', sql.NVarChar(200));

  benutzerTable.columns.add('b_lastName', sql.NVarChar(200));

  benutzerTable.columns.add('b_active', sql.Bit);

  const BenutzerList = req.body;

  BenutzerList.forEach(benutzer=> {

    benutzerTable.rows.add(

      benutzer.b_id,
      benutzer.b_firstName,
      benutzer.b_lastName,
      benutzer.b_active
    )
  });

    let  pool = await  sql.connect(config);

    let  addBenutzer = await  pool.request()

    .input('benutzerList', benutzerTable)

    .execute("updateBenutzer");

    return  addBenutzer.recordsets;

  }
  catch (error) {

    console.log(error);

  }

}

router.route('/addBenutzer').post((request, response) => {

    let Daten = JSON.stringify(request.body);

    benutzerController.addBenutzer(Daten).then(result => {

        response.status(201).json(result);

    });

})
```

-> hier is the array what i'm giving in postman:

```
[

    {
        "id": 1,

        "firstName": "Max",

        "lastName": "Müller",

        "active": true
    },

    {
        "id": 15,

        "firstName": "Ben",

        "lastName": "Kane",

        "active": true
    }

]
```

It supose to update id 1 and insert id 15 but unfortunatly doesn't work, i will be appreciate for your help.

Comment: What do you mean _"but unfortunatly doesn't work"_? Do you get error messages? Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69626842/edit) your question to include those error messages - as text.

Comment: You seem to have some naming discrepancies - the JSON data and table type definition use the names `id, firstName, lastname, active` yet most of your code uses `b_id, b_firstName, b_lastname, b_active` instead.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thank you for your response, i edit all the parameters now, i'm using in json data and table and table type as well  the parameters id, firstName, lastName, active. But doesn't work either i'm getting an a json status created but when i check my Table i don't find anychange or new insert.

Comment: The JSON blob uses `id, ..., active` and the Node code uses `benutzerTable.rows.add(benutzer.b_id, ..., benutzer.b_active)`. If you watch it in SQL Profiler or Extended Events it's probably sending two rows of `null` values, try using `benutzerTable.rows.add(benutzer.id, ..., benutzer.active)` instead.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I already changed it but it didn't help :( i'm still getting the same json status 201-created in postman. and no insert no update

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, i figured out that the request-body is undefined and that function forEach too. i have already installed body-parser and i added to my index.js. It look like that : 
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json()) . but i don't know why is undefined!

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is my solution, the request.body was undefind because request was not defined. i edited my function to look much better and i added req and res parameters to async function: 

router.post('/addBenutzer', async(req, res) => {
    try {    
    const benutzerTable = new sql.Table();
    benutzerTable.columns.add('id', sql.Int);
    benutzerTable.columns.add('firstName', sql.NVarChar(200));
    benutzerTable.columns.add('lastName', sql.NVarChar(200));
    benutzerTable.columns.add('active', sql.Bit);
    const BenutzerList = req.body;
    BenutzerList.forEach(benutzer => {
      benutzerTable.rows.add(
        benutzer.id,
        benutzer.firstName,
        benutzer.lastName,
        benutzer.active
      )
    });
      let  pool = await  sql.connect(config);
      let  addBenutzer = await  pool.request()
      .input('benutzerList', benutzerTable)
      .execute("updateBenutzer");
      res.send(req.body);
      return  addBenutzer.recordsets;
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }`enter code here`
});
```